Authenticated Supabase requests to NextJS API from a chrome extension
I have setup a fully functional NextJS web app with Supabase SSR authentication. Everything works great!
But now I need to make authenticated requests to my NextJS API protected routes from a different static FE client (in my case a chrome extension)
I'm able to login the user to my extension using simply supabase js.
But i'm having issues trying to make requests to my NextJS API route handlers that require user authentication.
I know Supabase SSR uses cookies on the web app. Is there a way I should create a cookie in my chome extension?
I also know I have access to an access_token in my chrome extension... any way I can use that?
Just wondering what is the best approach here.
Thanks in advance!
